# Issue using DLookUp function in Access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

Ok so I have a text box on my main form and I want it to show the quantity of a product chosen from a drop down list.

Now there is a complication, there are 3 stock locations for each product, but this is simplified as I have 3 different levels stored on the same record for a product, with different column names.

So what I need to do is search for the name of the correct column to find the right stock location (again from a drop down).

My stock level column heading is stored in the variable "Branch" which is a string.

Here is my code.

```
Me.txtSourceDescQty.Value = DLookup(Branch, "[products/stock]", "[Product Code] = " & Me.cmbSource.Value)
```

[image: Error message]

This is the error I get. 'Stock Level' is the column header for one of the stock locations, which is stored under the variable "Branch" in the line of code.

`cmbSource` is the combo box where the product code is selected.

Comment: Is product code text? If so, you need to add quotes. Does Branch contain spaces or special characters? if so, you need to add square brackets.

Comment: Where do I add the quotes for product code?

Comment: @thornomad has added an answer for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `Me.cmbSource.Value` needs to appear in quotes:

```
Me.txtSourceDescQty.Value = DLookup(Branch, "[products/stock]", "[Product Code] = '" & Me.cmbSource.Value & "'")
```

Comment: This should be fine as long as `branch` does not contain anything dicey.